# How to get difference in days between two dates from a csv in python?

Tags: python, pandas, date

So I'm trying to get the number of days between these two dates ("today" and a prior date) from a csv file. I'm using the datetime library, i can get the delta (difference between the two dates), but I can't get the number of days. If i try to use .days it returns me an error, stating it cannot convert series to datetime.
I just wanna get the number of days in int or float to use in a code I'm working on. Can anyone give me some direction? I've tried everything and done a lot of prior research here on Stackoverflow and other websites.

Here's the code below.

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.read_csv("serv.csv",parse_dates=["PasswordLastSet"])

for row in df:
    d1 = pd.to_datetime(datetime.today())
    d2 = (df["PasswordLastSet"])
    delta = d1-d2
    days = delta.datetime.days
```

tried some different librarys, tried converting the delta to datetime, tried turning it to a string and filter that string but no sucess. I just want to get the number of days, like "10" or "60" so i can make some math with it later on.

Answer (score 0):

convert passwordlastset to datetime and subtract from today

```
df['delta']=(datetime.today() - pd.to_datetime(df['PasswordLastSet'])).dt.days
df
```

```
PasswordLastSet     delta
0   2019-09-10 11:11    1142
1   2019-10-07 11:13    1115
2   2019-11-04 11:16    1087
3   2019-11-28 11:20    1063
```